# Div Displays on Image Hover, But Blinks When I Hover Over It

Tags: jquery, html

I have a section of this site where when I hover over an image (`class="background"`) a div fades in (div `class="portfolio-hover"`). This works properly.

Now, when the div fades in and I hover over the div itself, it blinks once. I can't figure out what's going on.

You can find it here in this JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y3ec7sua/1/ . Here, in the 'Portfolio' section, hover over a green box (the image). A blue bar on the bottom shows up. Now when I hover over the blue bar, it blinks. I already added `.stop()` to the `fadeOut`, but it still blinks. How can I get it to remain static and not blink when it's displayed and hovered over?

Also, any ideas how I can get only the box being hovered over to show the div, instead of all divs showing at once?

HTML Section of images and div hover

```
<div id="portfolio" class="container-fluid">
            <h1>Portfolio</h1>
            <div class="row" >
                <div class="col-sm-4" id="portfolio1">
                    <div class="portfolio_custom">
                        <img src="safe.png" class="img-responsive background"> <!-- Background Image -->
                        <div class="portfolio-hover"> <!-- Hover Content -->
                            <img src="yellow_circle.png" class="img-responsive overlay">
                            <div class="text-hover">
                                <p>HTML5/CSS3</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4" id="portfolio2">
                    <div class="portfolio_custom">
                        <img src="cake.png" class="img-responsive background"> <!-- Background Image -->
                        <div class="portfolio-hover"> <!-- Hover Content -->
                            <img src="yellow_circle.png" class="img-responsive overlay">
                            <div class="text-hover">
                                <p>HTML5/CSS3/JavaScript/jQuery</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4" id="portfolio3">
                    <div class="portfolio_custom">
                        <img src="safe.png" class="img-responsive background"> <!-- Background Image -->
                        <div class="portfolio-hover"> <!-- Hover Content -->
                            <img src="yellow_circle.png" class="img-responsive overlay">
                            <div class="text-hover">
                                <p>HTML5/CSS3/JavaScript/jQuery</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $('.background').hover(function(){
        $('.portfolio-hover').fadeIn(100);
    }, 
    function(){
        $('.portfolio-hover').stop().fadeOut();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your `<img src="cake.png" class="img-responsive background">` and `<div class="portfolio-hover">` are in the same position (both are child of `<div class="portfolio_custom">` and relative).

So when you hover over `.background`, it does `fadeIn`, but in the instant you hover over the `.background` and if you move your mouse a little bit and it hover over `.portfolio-hover` it won't hover over the `.background` so it does the `fadeOut`, but if in the instant you move your mouse a little bit again, it will again hover over `.background` so it `fadeIn` again.

What you need to do is trigger the `hover` function on the parent which is `.portfolio_custom`, so it would still in the hover for the current item. Change your code to this:

```
$('.portfolio_custom').hover(function(){
```

Then with only that, you will trigger `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` to all of the `.portfolio-hover`, so you need to change the inside of `hover` to

```
$('.portfolio_custom').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.portfolio-hover').fadeIn(100);
}, 
function(){
    $(this).find('.portfolio-hover').stop().fadeOut();
});
```

So it would only trigger the `fadeIn` to the `.portfolio-hover` of the hovered `item`

Here's the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y3ec7sua/2/)